# download files with eventlet

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, eventlet

I want to use threads to download many files at once.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import eventlet
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch(url, fl):
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fl)
  return url, fl

pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
for url, fl in pool.imap(fetch, dlList, dlFList):
  print("downloaded " + url + " to " + fl)
```

Where `dList` is a list of `urls` and `dlFList` is a list of destination files.

However, I get the error:

> TypeError: fetch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fl'

How do I correctly pass more than 1 argument with this `pool.imap`

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `fetch` function was read only (for example in other library), then you'd have to `imap` over an intermediate function.

```
pool.imap(lambda (u,f): fetch(u, f), zip(dlList, dlFList))
```

but since you can control the mapping function, change it to accept a tuple of url and filename.

```
def fetch(t):
  url, filename = t
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
  return t

pool.imap(fetch, zip(dlList, dlFList))
```

Don't feel like tupling? Make filename calculable from url, for example, via dictionary lookup or string processing.

```
url_filename_map = dict(zip(dlList, dlFList))  # or build dict some other way

def fetch(url):
  filename = url_filename_map[url]
  # or
  filename = '/path/prefix/' + hashlib.md5(url).hexdigest()
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
  return url, filename

pool.imap(fetch, url_filename_map)  # same as imap(fetch, urlmap.keys())
```